# How to resolve the Google pay api error in my Android app?

Tags: android, google-play-services, stripe-payments

I am using using android pay api in my application, before I am using  'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0' in my dependencies and everything is working fine. But once that I change the version of my google play services to com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0 when I click the wallet fragment button my apps shows a pop up error that says:

```
 "We couldn't complete your task because of a technical issure"
```

I try to log if the  `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` calls `OnConnected(Bundle bundle)` and I saw that google api is connected.

this is the code that I use in my fragment:

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ride, container, false);



    WalletFragmentOptions walletFragmentOptions = WalletFragmentOptions.newBuilder()
            .setEnvironment(WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
            .setTheme(WalletConstants.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT)
            .setMode(WalletFragmentMode.BUY_BUTTON)
            .build();

    mWalletFragment = SupportWalletFragment.newInstance(walletFragmentOptions);

    MaskedWalletRequest maskedWalletRequest = MaskedWalletRequest.newBuilder()

            // Request credit card tokenization with Stripe by specifying tokenization parameters:
            .setPaymentMethodTokenizationParameters(PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters.newBuilder()
                    .setPaymentMethodTokenizationType(PaymentMethodTokenizationType.PAYMENT_GATEWAY)
                    .addParameter("gateway", "stripe")
                    .addParameter("stripe:publishableKey", PUBLISHABLE_KEY)
                    .addParameter("stripe:version", com.stripe.Stripe.VERSION)
                    .build())

                    // You want the shipping address:
            .setShippingAddressRequired(true)

                    // Price set as a decimal:
            .setEstimatedTotalPrice("20.00")
            .setCurrencyCode("USD")
            .build();

    // Set the parameters:
    WalletFragmentInitParams initParams = WalletFragmentInitParams.newBuilder()
            .setMaskedWalletRequest(maskedWalletRequest)
            .setMaskedWalletRequestCode(LOAD_MASKED_WALLET_REQUEST_CODE)
            .build();

    // Initialize the fragment:
    mWalletFragment.initialize(initParams);

    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.dynamic_wallet_button_fragment, mWalletFragment)
            .commit();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Wallet.API, new Wallet.WalletOptions.Builder()
                    .setEnvironment(WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
                    .setTheme(WalletConstants.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT)
                    .build())
            .build();

    return view;
}


 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Log.i("requestCode"+requestCode, "resultCode"+resultCode);
    }



public void loadMaskedWallet(MaskedWallet maskedWallet){
    FullWalletRequest fullWalletRequest = FullWalletRequest.newBuilder()
            .setCart(Cart.newBuilder()
                    .setCurrencyCode("USD")
                    .setTotalPrice("20.00")
                    .addLineItem(LineItem.newBuilder() // Identify item being purchased
                            .setCurrencyCode("USD")
                            .setQuantity("1")
                            .setDescription("Premium Llama Food")
                            .setTotalPrice("20.00")
                            .setUnitPrice("20.00")
                            .build())
                    .build())
            .setGoogleTransactionId(maskedWallet.getGoogleTransactionId())
            .build();
    Wallet.Payments.loadFullWallet(mGoogleApiClient, fullWalletRequest, LOAD_FULL_WALLET_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

This is the onActivityResult in my hosting activity:

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


          if (requestCode == LOAD_MASKED_WALLET_REQUEST_CODE){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                MaskedWallet maskedWallet = data.getParcelableExtra(WalletConstants.EXTRA_MASKED_WALLET);
                mRideFragment.loadMaskedWallet(maskedWallet);
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                cancelRide();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == LOAD_FULL_WALLET_REQUEST_CODE){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                FullWallet fullWallet = data.getParcelableExtra(WalletConstants.EXTRA_FULL_WALLET);
                mRideFragment.loadFullWallet(fullWallet, mUserId);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's the error you see within the app? Is anything captured on logcat?

Comment: the error is shown on the dialog @Andy. the credit card selection from google pay api is displayed and when I clicked a specific gmail account to use, a dialog message is shown saying "We couldn't complete your task because of a technical issue."

Comment: I have stripe test card that is stored  in my gmail account